# Funny things students say when learning mathematics

Tags: general-pedagogy, students-mistakes, student-question, mathematical-discourse

I apologize for the "softness" of this enquiry, but as mathematics educators I believe these are some of the most rewarding moments of teaching our discipline. Having said that, may I share with you a story of teaching an online high school student elementary Algebra, after which, I replied "thanks for trying to learn", the student answered, "I always try before I give up." :D

I am simply looking for stories, to share with other mathematics educators, that made them laugh out loud. This, imho, is part of the reward in teaching.

Comment: Could I ask you to make more precise what you are looking for. It is not clear to me what type of answers you seek. Especially your exmaple makes the situation a bit unclear. It is neither specific to math, nor is it really positive (so I do not see how it is rewarding).

Comment: I am simply looking for stories, to share with other mathematics educators, that made them laugh out loud. This, imho, is part of the reward in teaching. Btw, thank you for retagging the question.

Comment: Are you looking for back fired aha- moments from students? Something like 
"Vacuum? I have it in my head, but I don't know how to explain it"

Comment: @Thinkeye sure that works :-)

Comment: I see. Let us see how it will develop. For the tags: you are welcome.

Comment: Here's a classic from MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/a/53905/31308

Comment: Indeed, a classic @DanielHast

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic isn't about teaching or learning mathematics. No answer to this question will impact mathematics education or support math educators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From John Stembridge's web site at http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/plans.html :

"Are we going to have to think today, or is it going to be all math?"

--a student in Phil Hanlon's Math 115 class

Comment: That's a good one. It is sometimes amazing (though not really in a good way) that some students manage to answer a question that stumped them completely *after* being told they should just forget they are trying to solve a math problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a colleague when I was teaching in Asia who was new to teaching high school, but was a very accomplished Mathematician. In one of his first lessons he was teaching simultaneous equations, and said that he would teach them two methods to do this. He thought that offering an option would endear him to the students. A student then put his hand up, and with all seriousness said:

"Thank you, but previous teacher taught *All Known Methods*"

Comment: That's the idea :D Any story, related to teaching math, that made you laugh out loud.

Answer (score 2):

From a student learning real analysis:
*The sequence diverges because the Cauchy criterion is dissatisfied.*